# How can I parse an Android layout xml file to create a replica for help pages?

Tags: android, xml, canvas, layout-inflater, xmlpullparser

I want to take layout files for activities and use them to create an image of that activity on a help page. I want to draw the activity replica on a canvas. I would like the image of the activity shown on the canvas to be directly linked to the layout files so that when I change the activity's layout the help page picture on the canvas will automatically update.

Initially, I want to use menu xml files to get the icons used in the ActionBar and show them on the canvas. I understand how to display the icons on the canvas. I want to know how to get the icons used (eg. `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"`) out of the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_save"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
          android:title="@string/save"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_delete"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
          android:title="@string/delete"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
          android:title="@string/help"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I have seen XMLPullParser as an option. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Is there a specific parser that is good for android layout files? It looks like XMLPullParser won't handle and separate the strings.

Comment: You can simply re-use the same XML layout for another activity or fragment.

Comment: I was thinking about using a fragment within the Help Activity. I'd ideally like to get it onto a canvas so that I can add animations over the top of the layout replica.

Comment: Android is very open. You can easily do either. For my Android applications I usually keep menu's simple: "Feedback", "About", "Settings", "Help".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hacked the MenuInflater XMLPullParser to do what I want. Here is the code for the CustomMenuInflater. I left the commented out code in as I thought it could be useful for people wanting to access different features of the MenuInflater.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.canvaslayout;

//import com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.InflateException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This class is used to instantiate menu XML files into Menu objects.
 * <p>
 * For performance reasons, menu inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of
 * XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible
 * to use MenuInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime;
 * it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.
 * <em>something</em> file.)
 */
public class CustomMenuInflater {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MenuInflater";

    /** Menu tag name in XML. */
    private static final String XML_MENU = "menu";

    /** Group tag name in XML. */
    private static final String XML_GROUP = "group";

    /** Item tag name in XML. */
    private static final String XML_ITEM = "item";

    private static final int NO_ID = 0;

    private static final Class<?>[] ACTION_VIEW_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNATURE = new Class[] {Context.class};

    private static final Class<?>[] ACTION_PROVIDER_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNATURE = ACTION_VIEW_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNATURE;

    private final Object[] mActionViewConstructorArguments;

    private final Object[] mActionProviderConstructorArguments;

    private Context mContext;
    private Object mRealOwner;

    /**
     * Constructs a menu inflater.
     * 
     * @see Activity#getMenuInflater()
     */
    public CustomMenuInflater(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mRealOwner = context;
        mActionViewConstructorArguments = new Object[] {context};
        mActionProviderConstructorArguments = mActionViewConstructorArguments;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a menu inflater.
     *
     * @see Activity#getMenuInflater()
     * @hide
     */
    public CustomMenuInflater(Context context, Object realOwner) {
        mContext = context;
        mRealOwner = realOwner;
        mActionViewConstructorArguments = new Object[] {context};
        mActionProviderConstructorArguments = mActionViewConstructorArguments;
    }

    /**
     * Inflate a menu hierarchy from the specified XML resource. Throws
     * {@link InflateException} if there is an error.
     * 
     * @param menuRes Resource ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
     *            <code>R.menu.main_activity</code>)
     * @param menu The Menu to inflate into. The items and submenus will be
     *            added to this Menu.
     */
    public void inflate(int menuRes, ArrayList<Integer> intArray) { // TODO inflate to where?
        XmlResourceParser parser = null;
        try {
            parser = mContext.getResources().getLayout(menuRes);
            AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
            Log.d("attrs inflate", Integer.toString(attrs.getAttributeCount()));
            parseMenu(parser, attrs, intArray);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            throw new InflateException("Error inflating menu XML", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InflateException("Error inflating menu XML", e);
        } finally {
            if (parser != null) parser.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called internally to fill the given menu. If a sub menu is seen, it will
     * call this recursively.
     */
    private void parseMenu(XmlPullParser parser, AttributeSet attrs, ArrayList<Integer> intArray) // TODO parse tp where
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        MenuState menuState = new MenuState();
        //intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Log.d("attrs parse", Integer.toString(attrs.getAttributeCount()));

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        String tagName;
        boolean lookingForEndOfUnknownTag = false;
        String unknownTagName = null;



        // This loop will skip to the menu start tag
        do {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                tagName = parser.getName();
                if (tagName.equals(XML_MENU)) {
                    // Go to next tag
                    eventType = parser.next();
                    break;
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("Expecting menu, got " + tagName);
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

        boolean reachedEndOfMenu = false;
        while (!reachedEndOfMenu) {
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (lookingForEndOfUnknownTag) {
                        break;
                    }

                    tagName = parser.getName();
                    if (tagName.equals(XML_GROUP)) {
                       /* menuState.readGroup(attrs);*/
                    } else if (tagName.equals(XML_ITEM)) {
                        menuState.readItem(attrs);
                    } else if (tagName.equals(XML_MENU)) {
                        // A menu start tag denotes a submenu for an item
                        //SubMenu subMenu = menuState.addSubMenuItem();
                        // TODO what if there is a submenu


                        // Parse the submenu into returned SubMenu
                        //parseMenu(parser, attrs, subMenu);
                    } else {
                        lookingForEndOfUnknownTag = true;
                        unknownTagName = tagName;
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    tagName = parser.getName();
                    if (lookingForEndOfUnknownTag && tagName.equals(unknownTagName)) {
                        lookingForEndOfUnknownTag = false;
                        unknownTagName = null;
                    } else if (tagName.equals(XML_GROUP)) {
                        menuState.resetGroup();
                    } else if (tagName.equals(XML_ITEM)) {
                        // Add the item if it hasn't been added (if the item was
                        // a submenu, it would have been added already)

                        if (!menuState.hasAddedItem()) {
                            /*if (menuState.itemActionProvider != null &&
                                    menuState.itemActionProvider.hasSubMenu()) {
                                menuState.addSubMenuItem();
                            } else {
                                menuState.addItem();
                            }*/
                            menuState.addItem(intArray);
                        }
                        // TODO addItem() goes here
                    } else if (tagName.equals(XML_MENU)) {
                        reachedEndOfMenu = true;
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected end of document");
            }

            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }

    /*private static class InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener // TODO onClickListener?
            implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        private static final Class<?>[] PARAM_TYPES = new Class[] { MenuItem.class };

        private Object mRealOwner;
        private Method mMethod;

        public InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener(Object realOwner, String methodName) {
            mRealOwner = realOwner;
            Class<?> c = realOwner.getClass();
            try {
                mMethod = c.getMethod(methodName, PARAM_TYPES);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                InflateException ex = new InflateException(
                        "Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler " + methodName +
                        " in class " + c.getName());
                ex.initCause(e);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            try {
                if (mMethod.getReturnType() == Boolean.TYPE) {
                    return (Boolean) mMethod.invoke(mRealOwner, item);
                } else {
                    mMethod.invoke(mRealOwner, item);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }*/

    /**
     * State for the current menu.
     * <p>
     * Groups can not be nested unless there is another menu (which will have
     * its state class).
     */
    private class MenuState { // TODO MenuState needs menu?
        //private Menu menu;

        /*
         * Group state is set on items as they are added, allowing an item to
         * override its group state. (As opposed to set on items at the group end tag.)
         */
        private int groupId;
        private int groupCategory;
        private int groupOrder;
        private int groupCheckable;
        private boolean groupVisible;
        private boolean groupEnabled;

        private boolean itemAdded;
        private int itemId;
        private int itemCategoryOrder;
        private CharSequence itemTitle;
        private CharSequence itemTitleCondensed;
        private int itemIconResId;
        private char itemAlphabeticShortcut;
        private char itemNumericShortcut;
        /**
         * Sync to attrs.xml enum:
         * - 0: none
         * - 1: all
         * - 2: exclusive
         */
        private int itemCheckable;
        private boolean itemChecked;
        private boolean itemVisible;
        private boolean itemEnabled;

        /**
         * Sync to attrs.xml enum, values in MenuItem:
         * - 0: never
         * - 1: ifRoom
         * - 2: always
         * - -1: Safe sentinel for "no value".
         */
        private int itemShowAsAction;

        private int itemActionViewLayout;
        private String itemActionViewClassName;
        private String itemActionProviderClassName;

        private String itemListenerMethodName;

        private android.view.ActionProvider itemActionProvider;

        private static final int defaultGroupId = NO_ID;
        private static final int defaultItemId = NO_ID;
        private static final int defaultItemCategory = 0;
        private static final int defaultItemOrder = 0;
        private static final int defaultItemCheckable = 0;
        private static final boolean defaultItemChecked = false;
        private static final boolean defaultItemVisible = true;
        private static final boolean defaultItemEnabled = true;

        static final int CATEGORY_MASK = 0xffff0000; // TODO may change with new versions of Android - from android.view.Menu
        static final int USER_MASK = 0x0000ffff; // TODO may change with new versions of Android - from android.view.Menu

        public MenuState() {
            //this.menu = menu;

            resetGroup();
        }

        public void resetGroup() {
            groupId = defaultGroupId;
            groupCategory = defaultItemCategory;
            groupOrder = defaultItemOrder;
            groupCheckable = defaultItemCheckable;
            groupVisible = defaultItemVisible;
            groupEnabled = defaultItemEnabled;
        }

        /**
         * Called when the parser is pointing to a group tag.
         */
        /*public void readGroup(AttributeSet attrs) {
            Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
            TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    toIntArray(res.getIdentifier(R.styleable.MenuGroup)));

            groupId = a.getResourceId(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_id", "styleable", "R"), defaultGroupId);
            groupCategory = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_menuCategory", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemCategory);
            groupOrder = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_orderInCategory", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemOrder);
            groupCheckable = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_checkableBehavior", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemCheckable);
            groupVisible = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_visible", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemVisible);
            groupEnabled = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuGroup_enabled", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemEnabled);

            a.recycle();
        }*/

        /**
         * Called when the parser is pointing to an item tag.
         */
        public void readItem(AttributeSet attrs) {
            Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
            TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.example.canvaslayout.R.styleable.MenuItem);
            Log.d("a how many items", Integer.toString(a.length())); 
            Log.d("a 1", "nout:" + attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto", "MenuItem_id")); 


            // Inherit attributes from the group as default value
            itemId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MenuItem_id, defaultItemId);
            /*final int category = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_menuCategory", "styleable", "R"), groupCategory);
            final int order = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_orderInCategory", "styleable", "R"), groupOrder);
            itemCategoryOrder = (category & CATEGORY_MASK) | (order & USER_MASK);*/
            itemTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.MenuItem_title);
            Log.d("itemTitle", a.getString(R.styleable.MenuItem_title));
            /*itemTitleCondensed = a.getText(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_titleCondensed", "styleable", "R"));*/
            itemIconResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MenuItem_icon, 0);
            Log.d("placed:itemIconResId", Integer.toString(itemIconResId)); 
            /*itemAlphabeticShortcut =
                    getShortcut(a.getString(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_alphabeticShortcut", "styleable", "R")));
            itemNumericShortcut =
                    getShortcut(a.getString(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_numericShortcut", "styleable", "R")));
            if (a.hasValue(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_checkable", "styleable", "R"))) {
                // Item has attribute checkable, use it
                itemCheckable = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_checkable", "styleable", "R"), false) ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                // Item does not have attribute, use the group's (group can have one more state
                // for checkable that represents the exclusive checkable)
                itemCheckable = groupCheckable;
            }
            itemChecked = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_checked", "styleable", "R"), defaultItemChecked);
            itemVisible = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_visible", "styleable", "R"), groupVisible);
            itemEnabled = a.getBoolean(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_enabled", "styleable", "R"), groupEnabled);
            itemShowAsAction = a.getInt(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_showAsAction", "styleable", "R"), -1);
            itemListenerMethodName = a.getString(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_onClick", "styleable", "R"));
            itemActionViewLayout = a.getResourceId(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_actionLayout", "styleable", "R"), 0);
            itemActionViewClassName = a.getString(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_actionViewClass", "styleable", "R"));
            itemActionProviderClassName = a.getString(res.getIdentifier("MenuItem_actionProviderClass", "styleable", "R"));

            Log.d("a", Integer.toString(a.getIndexCount()));


            final boolean hasActionProvider = itemActionProviderClassName != null;
            if (hasActionProvider && itemActionViewLayout == 0 && itemActionViewClassName == null) {
                itemActionProvider = newInstance(itemActionProviderClassName,
                            ACTION_PROVIDER_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNATURE,
                            mActionProviderConstructorArguments);
            } else {
                if (hasActionProvider) {
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Ignoring attribute 'actionProviderClass'."
                            + " Action view already specified.");
                }
                itemActionProvider = null;
            }*/

            a.recycle();

            itemAdded = false;
        }

        private char getShortcut(String shortcutString) {
            if (shortcutString == null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return shortcutString.charAt(0);
            }
        }

        /*private void setItem(MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(itemChecked)
                .setVisible(itemVisible)
                .setEnabled(itemEnabled)
                .setCheckable(itemCheckable >= 1)
                .setTitleCondensed(itemTitleCondensed)
                .setIcon(itemIconResId)
                .setAlphabeticShortcut(itemAlphabeticShortcut)
                .setNumericShortcut(itemNumericShortcut);

            if (itemShowAsAction >= 0) {
                item.setShowAsAction(itemShowAsAction);
            }

            if (itemListenerMethodName != null) {
                if (mContext.isRestricted()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
                            + "be used within a restricted context");
                }
                item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
                        new InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener(mRealOwner, itemListenerMethodName));
            }

            if (item instanceof MenuItemImpl) {
                MenuItemImpl impl = (MenuItemImpl) item;
                if (itemCheckable >= 2) {
                    impl.setExclusiveCheckable(true);
                }
            }

            boolean actionViewSpecified = false;
            if (itemActionViewClassName != null) {
                View actionView = (View) newInstance(itemActionViewClassName,
                        ACTION_VIEW_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNATURE, mActionViewConstructorArguments);
                item.setActionView(actionView);
                actionViewSpecified = true;
            }
            if (itemActionViewLayout > 0) {
                if (!actionViewSpecified) {
                    item.setActionView(itemActionViewLayout);
                    actionViewSpecified = true;
                } else {
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Ignoring attribute 'itemActionViewLayout'."
                            + " Action view already specified.");
                }
            }
            if (itemActionProvider != null) {
                item.setActionProvider(itemActionProvider);
            }
        }

        public void addItem() {
            itemAdded = true;
            setItem(menu.add(groupId, itemId, itemCategoryOrder, itemTitle));
        }

        public SubMenu addSubMenuItem() {
            itemAdded = true;
            SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(groupId, itemId, itemCategoryOrder, itemTitle);
            setItem(subMenu.getItem());
            return subMenu;
        }*/


        public void addItem(ArrayList<Integer> integerArray) {
            itemAdded = true;
            integerArray.add(itemIconResId);
            Log.d("itemIconResId", Integer.toString(itemIconResId));
        }

        public void addSubMenuItem() {
            itemAdded = true;
            // TODO add submenu item added method

        }

        public boolean hasAddedItem() {
            return itemAdded;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private <T> T newInstance(String className, Class<?>[] constructorSignature,
                Object[] arguments) {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = mContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
                Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(constructorSignature);
                return (T) constructor.newInstance(arguments);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Cannot instantiate class: " + className, e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int[] toIntArray(int identifier) {
        int[] newIntArray = new int[1];
        newIntArray[0] = identifier;
        return newIntArray;
    }
}
```

The following is the xml attrs.xml file which is needed in conjunction with this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <!-- Base attributes that are available to all Item objects. -->
    <declare-styleable name="MenuItem">

        <!-- The ID of the item. -->
        <attr name="id" format="string" />

        <!-- The title associated with the item. -->
        <attr name="title" format="string" />

        <!-- The condensed title associated with the item.  This is used in situations where the
             normal title may be too long to be displayed. -->
        <attr name="titleCondensed" format="string" />

        <!-- The icon associated with this item.  This icon will not always be shown, so
             the title should be sufficient in describing this item. -->
        <attr name="icon" format="integer" />

        <!-- The alphabetic shortcut key.  This is the shortcut when using a keyboard
             with alphabetic keys. -->
        <attr name="alphabeticShortcut" format="string" />

        <!-- The numeric shortcut key.  This is the shortcut when using a numeric (e.g., 12-key)
             keyboard. -->
        <attr name="numericShortcut" format="string" />

        <!-- Whether the item is capable of displaying a check mark. -->
        <attr name="checkable" format="boolean" />

        <!-- Name of a method on the Context used to inflate the menu that will be
             called when the item is clicked. -->
        <attr name="onClick" format="string" />

        <!-- How this item should display in the Action Bar, if present. -->
        <attr name="showAsAction">
            <!-- Never show this item in an action bar, show it in the overflow menu instead.
                 Mutually exclusive with "ifRoom" and "always". -->
            <flag name="never" value="0" />
            <!-- Show this item in an action bar if there is room for it as determined
                 by the system. Favor this option over "always" where possible.
                 Mutually exclusive with "never" and "always". -->
            <flag name="ifRoom" value="1" />
            <!-- Always show this item in an actionbar, even if it would override
                 the system's limits of how much stuff to put there. This may make
                 your action bar look bad on some screens. In most cases you should
                 use "ifRoom" instead. Mutually exclusive with "ifRoom" and "never". -->
            <flag name="always" value="2" />
            <!-- When this item is shown as an action in the action bar, show a text
                 label with it even if it has an icon representation. -->
            <flag name="withText" value="4" />
            <!-- This item's action view collapses to a normal menu
                 item. When expanded, the action view takes over a
                 larger segment of its container. -->
            <flag name="collapseActionView" value="8" />
        </attr>

        <!-- An optional layout to be used as an action view.
             See {@link android.view.MenuItem#setActionView(android.view.View)}
             for more info. -->
        <attr name="actionLayout" format="reference" />

        <!-- The name of an optional View class to instantiate and use as an
             action view. See {@link android.view.MenuItem#setActionView(android.view.View)}
             for more info. -->
        <attr name="actionViewClass" format="string" />

        <!-- The name of an optional ActionProvider class to instantiate an action view
             and perform operations such as default action for that menu item. -->
        <attr name="actionProviderClass" format="string" />

    </declare-styleable>


</resources>
```

I then accessed the icon resIDs using the following code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> iconList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    CustomMenuInflater menuInf = new CustomMenuInflater(this);
    menuInf.inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, iconList);
```

The menu.xml must include `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` rather than `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

UPDATE: I changed the menu file to have two namespaces and repeated the icon line for each to make the icons show both in the help canvas and in the ActionBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_save"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
          myapp:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
          android:title="@string/save"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_delete"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
          myapp:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
          android:title="@string/delete"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_detail_help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
          myapp:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
          android:title="@string/help"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```